sample redshift function that return a value from a select stmt?
I'm looking for a sample redshift function that returns a value from a select stmt?
Redshift throws an error when trying to use select statement when used inside a function.
Sample:
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION test_dates_fn (input_date VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS VARCHAR stable AS $$

DECLARE test_date VARCHAR;

BEGIN 
select test_date from test_table where test_date like (select to_char(input_date::date, 'YYYY-MM')) || '%'; 
return test_date 
end; 
$$ language sql;


Functions can’t have variables only procedures can. Why do you need a function for this specific thing? Seems like all you want is “ select to_char(input_date::date, 'YYYY-MM')) || '%' “
